# Can I run two different awk commands in 1

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I can use this awk command to get last line of log file:

```
awk 'END{print}' /home/jj1/.pia_manager/log/pia_nw.log
```

And I can use this awk command to extract a substring:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' /home/jj1/.pia_manager/log/pia_nw.log
```

What i'd like to do is combine the two into one awk command. I've tried many combinations but can't get it to work. My goal is to send extracted string to Conky display. Can this be done, or do I need to use 2 commands?

Last line in log file always has string I need:

```
[2018-11-15T03:34:07.160Z] <debug> |tray| Translated status is "You are connected (Canada Vancouver)"
```

The part in parenthesis is what I want. 
Resulting output:

```
Canada Vancouver
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the second field of the last line using that field separator:

```
awk -F"[()]" 'END {print $2}' /home/jj1/.pia_manager/log/pia_nw.log
```

Comment: muru Thank you for your solution. It's exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of the first awk to the second awk:

```
awk 'END{print}' /home/jj1/.pia_manager/log/pia_nw.log | awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}'
```

This variant is more safe (ignore last empty lines in file):

```
awk '/^$/ {nlstack=nlstack "\n";next;} END{printf "%s",nlstack; nlstack=""; print;}' /home/jj1/.pia_manager/log/pia_nw.log | awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: @ S_Flash-I was thinking that the 2 could be nested in a way that it would use only 1 instance of awk, but thanks. That works fine.

Comment: The line I need to extract from will always be the last. Are you saying there could be empty lines below that?

Comment: Yes, last non empty line. Also fixed second example containing your previous comment